# ImageView drawable not showing on MarshMallow

Tags: android, imageview

So I have an app that needs to support android 6. We have an image view

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/volumecontrol_leftbatterylevel"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            custom:srcFromBatteryPercent="@{hearingDeviceViewModel.leftBatteryPercent}"
            tools:src="@drawable/battery_full"
            android:visibility="@{hearingDeviceViewModel.hasLeftBatteryStateOfCharge ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            custom:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            custom:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

with binding adapter code of

```
    @BindingAdapter("srcFromBatteryPercent")
    public static void setSrcFromBatteryPercent(final ImageView view,
                                                final int batteryPercent) {
        Drawable drawable;
        if (batteryPercent > 90) {
            drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), R.drawable.battery_full);
        }
        else if (batteryPercent >= 80) {
            drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), R.drawable.battery_80);
        }
        else if (batteryPercent >= 60) {
            drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), R.drawable.battery_60);
        }
        else if (batteryPercent >= 40) {
            drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), R.drawable.battery_40);
        }
        else if (batteryPercent >= 20) {
            drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), R.drawable.battery_20);
        }
        else {
            drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), R.drawable.battery_alert);
        }
        //view.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        view.setBackground(drawable);
    }
```

This works perfectly fine on android 7 and above. What were seeing on Android 6 (Nexus 5 and Galaxy s5, so it's not just one device) is that the image isn't there. When I color the background of the image, it shows the color, and there is space there. The drawable resource is an xml resource, so it's not a nodpi folder problem.

Any ideas

Comment: Do you use androidx.appcompat:appcompat support library and AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: We use `implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"` and yes our activity extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: Your activity must extend `AppCompatActivity`, for proper work of appcompat.
If everything is done right - then instead of ImageView AppCompatImageView will be inflated, which can work with vectors properly, using setImageDrawable method

Comment: Sorry edited my comment since I misread yours the first time. Yes we extend AppCompatActivity

Comment: Then, if removing  `custom:` from `custom:srcFromBatteryPercent` doesn't work - something wrong with your vector, android framework change it's way to work with vectors quite often.

Comment: I've tried using `android:src=...` and still nothing... It works just fine on higher versions.